# How to build GStreamer 1.14.1 on Android Studio 3.3 with ndk build?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, gstreamer

I want to build GStreamer 1.14.1 on Android Studio 3.3 with gradle 4.10.1, for android API 27 with armeabi-v7a architecture without success. This is the error i'm getting when i try to build:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/folavarria/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/folavarria/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/StreamingApp/app/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/folavarria/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/StreamingApp/app/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/home/folavarria/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/StreamingApp/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/folavarria/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/StreamingApp/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/Application.mk GSTREAMER_JAVA_SRC_DIR=src GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID=/home/folavarria/Android/Sdk/gstreamer/1.14.1 GSTREAMER_ASSETS_DIR=src/assets /home/folavarria/Projects/AndroidStudioProjects/StreamingApp/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtutorial-2.so}
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.c

clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
make: *** [gst-build-armeabi-v7a/gstreamer_android.o] Error 1
```

I tried to silence argument unused warning with "-Wno-unused-command-line-argument" and "-Wno-error" cflags on Android.mk and build.gradle, but isn't working.

Also tried with other GStreamer versions and i'm getting the same error. Even tried with different ndk versions (r15c, r16b and r19b), but this error keeps showing up.

Edit: I tried with Cerbero but isn't compatible with my OS, so i downloaded the latest GStreamer version and this error has gone, now i'm getting other error on Android.mk which is:

```
SYSROOT_LINK not defined
```

This was solved commenting a line on Gstreamer-SDK/armv7/share/gst-android/ndk-build/GStreamer.mk that was calling SYSROOT_LINK variable that wasn't defined on line 168.

```
ifdef SYSROOT
    SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(SYSROOT)
    SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT)
else
    ifdef SYSROOT_INC
        # $(call assert-defined, SYSROOT_LINK) <--- HERE!!!
        ifdef SYSROOT_LINK
            SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(SYSROOT_INC)
            SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT_LINK)
        endif
    else
        SYSROOT_GST_INC := $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-$(TARGET_ARCH)
        SYSROOT_GST_LINK := $(SYSROOT_GST_INC)
    endif
endif
```

And now it works perfectly, but seems that this isn't the proper way to solve this error.

Comment: Probably you should use [Cerbero](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html#crosscompilation-of-gstreamer) for cross GStreamer compilation.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.